# Excel how to count number in one field

Tags: excel

hi i need help with this, if someone know how to count how manny fields contains 3x "1" ( 111 or 1011 or 0010000100001 for example ) no more no less is there any formula for this ?

Field A1 : 101011 
Field A2 : 1011000
.... A511 : 11100010011

Excel 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in two steps, so there might be a better way. First find out how many "1" there is in each cell `=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,$B$1,""))` So in B1  you put "1". Drag that formula down.
Then its a matter og finding all the "3" in that new column you put that formula, either with a new formula or just filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot this helps :)

Comment: you could go a step further and wrap that formula in an if statement like this:  =IF(len(a1) -len(substitute(a1,$B$1,""))=3,"True","False")